# How to properly unit test a React component?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

When I test a react component, what are the best practices and what things should I test for? In normal tests I usually just test if the correct state+input leads to the correct state+output

But React components are a bit different. They have state+props+userInput which result in state+markup.

This can lead to many, many different potential scenarios. Do I need to test for the resulting state of all those scenarios?
The markup can be huge. Should I test if the whole markup-tree is as expected? Or just part of it? How do I determine what part of the markup to test?

Comment: It's not answer on question, but in most cases component markup should not be huge. In my opinion, it would be better to split big components on small components with little markup. This way, you can test them easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First obvious things to keep in mind:

- If the logic of the your components can be encapsulated into modules and tested independently, then do it. Example: For a calculator component, the calculations themselves can be tested independently of the component. I know this is obvious, but just to make the point.
- Break your components apart into smaller ones and test each of them granularly.

Regarding the component, always test:

- If the correct props will render the correct output (HTML).
- If the correct user interaction (click, key presses...) will fire the appropriate events and lead to the correct output (HTML). I usually don't deal with the component state at all during unit tests, as I don't find this a good practice. To test a TV you shouldn't have to open it.

If you are not sure about what library to use to test React components, I'd strongly recommend [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme).

Examples from their GitHub page:

```
describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  it('renders three <Foo /> components', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.length(3);
  });

  it('renders an `.icon-star`', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.icon-star')).to.have.length(1);
  });

  it('renders children when passed in', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <MyComponent>
        <div className="unique" />
      </MyComponent>
    );
    expect(wrapper.contains(<div className="unique" />)).to.equal(true);
  });

  it('simulates click events', () => {
    const onButtonClick = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Foo onButtonClick={onButtonClick} />
    );
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(onButtonClick).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: So how do you exactly test the HTML? Do you test if every single node is there? Or just key nodes?

Comment: @Moezalez Oh I definitely only look for key nodes. Otherwise it wouldn't be feasible. :). For example, if you want to test if clicking a dropdown button actually opens the dropdown, usually looking for 1 or 2 key elements should be enough. Testing is important but getting things done is even more important IMHO.